# asp.net mvc4 RC resolve url in data-* attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Since I have installed the mvc4 RC, the razor autoresolve url that replaces `~` by the application root does not work in html 5 `data-*` attributes. ie:

In ASP.NET MVC4 beta :

```
<table id="userTable" class="dataTable" data-table-source="~/api/user/Users">
    <tr>
        <td data-field="OperatorCode">
           @user.Code
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="~/user/edit">edit</a>
        </td>
</table>
```

was transformed in

```
<table id="userTable" class="dataTable" data-table-source="/api/user/Users">
    <tr>
        <td data-field="OperatorCode">
           operatorCode 1
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="/user/edit">edit</a>
        </td>
</table>
```

but in RC it is transformed in:

```
<table id="userTable" class="dataTable" data-table-source="~/api/user/Users">
    <tr>
        <td data-field="OperatorCode">
           operatorCode 1
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="/user/edit">edit</a>
        </td>
</table>
```

As you can see in this version the `~` remains.
Is it by design ? If yes, is there any configuration parameter to change in order to reactivate the resolution in html5 `data-*` attribute? I have no found the explanation in the release notes.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think that it's by design see [this article](http://vibrantcode.com/blog/2012/4/10/whats-new-in-razor-v2.html/). I see two cases: it's a big bug in the RC or something is broken on your machine. Try it in an empty new project, check that you are referencing the correct version of razor from the right place, try it with different attributes in different places (a href, etc.)...

Comment: Even with a brand new project it does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This also happens in MVC4 final.  It makes sense that this is by design to avoid cases where you don't want to have "~" resolved for certain data parameters.

Easy fix is to wrap them in @Url.Content again, not as nice but it works.

```
<html data-root="@Url.Content("~/")">
```

PS. I checked the MVC4 source code. There are no options to enable resolving of "data-" attributes. "data-" attributes are simply treated as literals.